# solve softplus for a base

Tags: logarithms

Solve 
$$ y=\log_{b}\left(1+b^{x}\right) $$
or the equivalent
$$ b^{y}-b^{x}=1 $$
for $ b $

if it helps, $b>0$ and $y>0$

This can model the value of a call option (ignoring time) as a function of the stock price with
$$ x = StockPrice - StrikePrice $$
$$ y = OptionValue $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **Welcome to the site !**.

The equation $$b^y-b^x=1\tag 1$$ cannot be solved in the most general case, even using special functions such as Lambert.

If $y >x$, let $t=b^x$ to make the equation
$$t^{\frac y x}-t=1$$ If $\frac y x$ is a small integer $(\leq 4)$, it will be a polynomial in $t$ which could be solved.Otherwise, you would need some numerical method to solve $(1)$ and Newton is probably the simplest to use.

If $y <x$, let $t=b^y$ to make the equation
$$-t^{\frac x y}+t=1$$

Considering the first case $y>x$, let $k=\frac y x$ and consider that you look for the zero of function
$$f(t)=t^k-t-1$$  and Newton iterates will be given by
$$t_{n+1}=t_n-\frac{t_n^k-t_n-1}{k t_n^{k-1}-1}$$ Since $f(1)=-1$, use $t_0=1$.

Trying for $k=\pi$, the iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & t_n \\
 0 & 1.00000 \\
 1 & 1.46694 \\
 2 & 1.32587 \\
 3 & 1.30483 \\
 4 & 1.30438
\end{array}
\right)$$

Now, go back to $b=t^{\frac{1}{x}}$.